# presentViewController needs to be dismissed with a slide while maintaing the view underneath

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I got an gridview. Each cell within that grid is clickable. If a cell is clicked, another viewcontroller must be presented as a modal viewcontroller. The presentedviewcontroller must slide in fro the right to the left. After that, the modalviewcontroller can be dismissed with a slide. How do i achieve this? I got some images to show it :

[image]

Both views are separate viewcontrollers.

**[Solution]**

The answer from Matthew pointed me in the right direction. What i needed was a UIPanGestureRecognizer. Because UISwipeGestureRecognizer only registers one single swipe and i needed the view to follow the users finger. I did the following to accomplish it :

If i cell is tapped inside my UICollectionView, the extra view needs to pop up. So i implemented the following code first :

```
/* The next piece of code represents the action called when a touch event occours on
 one of the UICollectionviewCells.
 */

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString* release_id = releases[indexPath.row][0];

    // Next boolean makes sure that only one new view can be seen. In the past, a user can click multiple cells and it allocs multiple instances of ReleaseViewController.
    if(releaseViewDismissed) {
        // Alloc UIViewController and initWithReleaseID does a request to a server to initialize some data.
        ReleaseViewController *releaseViewController = [[ReleaseViewController alloc] initWithReleaseID: release_id];
        // Create a new UIView and assign the height and width of the grid
        UIView *releaseViewHolder = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(gridSize.width, 0, gridSize.width, gridSize.height)];
        // Add the view of the releaseViewController as a subview of the newly created view.
        [releaseViewHolder addSubview:releaseViewController.view];
        // Then add the UIView with the view of the releaseViewController to the current UIViewController's view.       
        [self.view addSubview:releaseViewHolder];
        // Place the x coordinate of the new view to the same as width of the screen. Then after that get the x to 0 with an animation. 
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            releaseViewHolder.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, releaseViewHolder.frame.size.width, releaseViewHolder.frame.size.height);

             // This is important. alloc an UIPanGestureRecognizer and set the method that handles those events to handleSwipes.
            _panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipes:)];
            // Add the UIPanGestureRecognizer to the created view.
            [releaseViewHolder addGestureRecognizer:_panGestureRecognizer];

            releaseViewDismissed = NO;

        }];

    }

}
```

Then my handleSwipes is as follows:

```
-(void)handleSwipes:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender translationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:sender.view];
    CGRect newFrame = [sender view].frame;

    [sender setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:sender.view];

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {

        newFrame.origin.x = newFrame.origin.x + translation.x;
        // Makes sure it can't go beyond the left of the screen.
        if(newFrame.origin.x > 0) {

            [sender view].frame = newFrame;

        }

    }

    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){

        CGRect newFrame = [sender view].frame;

        CGFloat velocityX = (0.3*[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender velocityInView:self.view].x);

        // If the user swipes less then half of the screen, it has to bounce back.
        if(newFrame.origin.x < ([sender view].bounds.size.width/2)) {
            newFrame.origin.x = 0;
        }

        // If a user swipes fast, the velocity is added to the new x of the frame.
        if(newFrame.origin.x + velocityX > ([sender view].bounds.size.width/2)) {
            newFrame.origin.x = [sender view].bounds.size.width + velocityX;
            releaseViewDismissed = YES;
        }

        // Do it all with a animation.
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                         animations:^{

                            [sender view].frame = newFrame;

                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){

                             if(releaseViewDismissed) {
                                 // Finally remove the new view from the superView.
                                 [[sender view] removeFromSuperview];
                             }

                         }];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the presented view controller to slide in from the right to the left, it cannot be a modal view. @Juan suggested one way to achieve the right to left and swipe back, but it would result in the grid view being pushed out of the way by the new view. If you would like the new view to cover the grid view when it slides in, you will either need to accept the vertical slide of modal views or write your own code to slide the view in from the right -- the latter would not actually be all that difficult*.

As for the swipe to get back, the easiest way to do that from either a modally presented view or a view you animate in yourself is to use a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`. You create the recognizer, tell it what direction of swipe to look for, and you tell it what method to call when the swipe occurs.

*The gist of this approach is to create a `UIView`, add it as a subview of the grid view, and give it the same frame as your grid view but an x-position equal to the width of the view, and then use the following code to make the view animate in from the right.

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        slidingView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, slidingView.frame.size.width, slidingView.frame.size.height);
    }];
```

Comment: Accepted your answer because you pointed me in the right direction. Updated my post with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need is the following:

Create another controller that is going to handle navigation between these two (ContentViewController for example). This controller should have a ScrollView with paging enabled.

Here is a simple tutorial if you don´t already know how to do this: click [here](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uiscrollview-paging/)

Once the cell is clicked you have to:

1. Create the new ViewController to be shown.
2. Enable paging and add this ViewController to the ContentViewController
3. Force paging to this newly created ViewController

Additionally you have to add some logic so that when the user swipes to change back to the first page, paging is disabled until a new cell is clicked to repeat the process.